# TextInput not giving results in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am making a app where the user will enter the id of a company (i.e. PID) and click submit to get the results from SQL server database. I have created the below mentioned code but the code is not picking up the Input value in the SQL query. Please help. The code i have created so far is -

```
#install.packages("RODBC")
#install.packages("RODBCext")
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
library(RODBCext)
library(DT)
library(sqldf)

#UI

ui<-fluidPage(

  #Application Title

  titlePanel(title = "The is Default Database UI Testing Version!!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("PID","Enter company's PID",""),
      submitButton("Submit", icon("table"))

    ),

    mainPanel(

      h4("Database information"),
      DT::dataTableOutput({"mydata"})
      #tableOutput("mydata")
    )



  ))

#server

shinyServer <- function(input,output)

{

  #connect to database

con = odbcConnect('DDB')


  #build query
  query <-
"
select [COMPANY].[COMP_ID],[COMPANY].[PID], [COMPANY].[COMP_NAME],[CNTRY_NAME],EVENT.[EVENT_ID],[EVENT],[CONSID_DESC],[EVENT_YR],[EVENT_MON],[EVENT_DAY],[PATH]
               from EVENT inner join [dbo].[COMPANY] on EVENT.[COMP_ID] = [dbo].[COMPANY].[COMP_ID]
               inner join [dbo].[EVENT_TYPE] on EVENT.[EVENT_TYPE_ID] = [dbo].[EVENT_TYPE].[EVENT_TYPE_ID]
               inner join [dbo].[SPECIAL_CONSIDERATION] on EVENT.[CONSID_ID] = [dbo].[SPECIAL_CONSIDERATION].[CONSID_ID]
               inner join [dbo].[COUNTRY] on [dbo].[COMPANY].[CNTRY_CD] = [dbo].[COUNTRY].[CNTRY_CD]
               left join [dbo].[EVENT_DOC] on EVENT.[EVENT_ID] = [dbo].[EVENT_DOC].[EVENT_ID]
               where PID = '?,input$PID'"
(
res <- sqlQuery(con,query))

#ddf<-data.frame('res')

 # df[qry$mydata == input$select_mydata, ]
  output$mydata = DT::renderDataTable({res})
  #output$mydata = renderPrint({res})

}
  shinyApp(ui, shinyServer)
```

Comment: Not testing this, but looks like the `query` is wrong (no brainer). I think having `,input$PID'` in there is not a valid SQL syntax. It should be something like [this](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(shiny)
library(RODBC)
library(RODBCext)
library(DT)
library(sqldf)

con <- odbcConnect('DDB')
query <- "select [COMPANY].[COMP_ID],[COMPANY].[PID], [COMPANY].[COMP_NAME],[CNTRY_NAME],EVENT.[EVENT_ID],[EVENT],[CONSID_DESC],[EVENT_YR],[EVENT_MON],[EVENT_DAY],[PATH] from EVENT inner join [dbo].[COMPANY] on EVENT.[COMP_ID] = [dbo].[COMPANY].[COMP_ID] inner join [dbo].[EVENT_TYPE] on EVENT.[EVENT_TYPE_ID] = [dbo].[EVENT_TYPE].[EVENT_TYPE_ID] inner join [dbo].[SPECIAL_CONSIDERATION] on EVENT.[CONSID_ID] = [dbo].[SPECIAL_CONSIDERATION].[CONSID_ID] inner join [dbo].[COUNTRY] on [dbo].[COMPANY].[CNTRY_CD] = [dbo].[COUNTRY].[CNTRY_CD] left join [dbo].[EVENT_DOC] on EVENT.[EVENT_ID] = [dbo].[EVENT_DOC].[EVENT_ID] where PID = MYSHINYPID"

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = "The is Default Database UI Testing Version!!"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("PID","Enter company's PID",""),
      actionButton("Submit", icon("table"))

    ),
    mainPanel(
      h4("Database information"),
      dataTableOutput('mydata')
    )
  )
)


server <- function(session,input,output){

  sqldata <- eventReactive(input$Submit,{
    req(input$PID)
    query <- gsub("MYSHINYPID",input$PID,query)
    sqlQuery(con,query)
  })

  output$mydata <- DT::renderDataTable({
    sqldata()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

1. We going to use the string replace `gsub` for the query
2. Then will add `req()` for the PID so the user has to enter something
3. The connections ideally should be in the `global`, so all users can use it only once

Comment: Thank you so much, But I am still getting an error. ERROR : object 'MYSHINYPID' not found

Comment: @AshishTalgotra, sorry that should be a string, `"MYSHINYPID"` my bad

Comment: Sir after I made the required changes as suggested by you. I am now getting an error : 'data' must be 2-dimensional (e.g. data frame or matrix).

Comment: I think it might have been an issue with the sql query?